# How to do Hanging Punctuation in HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, typography

Is there a good way to do Hanging Punctuation in HTML / CSS today, since the browsers haven't implemented the `hanging-punctuation` property?

**Update:** A JavaScript solution would be nice, since it will enable me not to touch my html, besides the one line that references the script.

something like, 1) go through all p, span, and blockquote. If they start with ", ..., or something, then adjust the spacing. But I can't seem to figure out how to know how much to change the spacing, and how to handle anything other than the first character of the first line in an element.

```
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('p, span, blockquote');
console.log(elements);
var i = 0;
while (i < elements.length) {
  var el = elements[i];
  if (el.firstChild.nodeValue && el.firstChild.nodeValue.match(/^[".,']/)) {
    el.style.position = 'relative';
    el.style.left = '-.4em';
  }
  i += 1;
}
```

Code is a work in progress...

Comment: There are various tricks like negative margins and relative positioning that you could use in special cases, in a clumsy way. As asked, the question is too broad. Besides, the property hasn’t been *defined* yet; it has just been proposed in drafts (and marked as being at risk of removal). You should specify exactly what you would need, in particular case, and show your best attempt at it.

Comment: I was hoping for a Javascript solution simply because I can not change how I'm structuring my html. Something I type out '"' and it ends up at the left margin of a line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also fake it using `:before` and `:after`:

```css
p {
    margin-left: 1em;
    background-color: #eee;
}

p:before {
    content: '"';
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -.4em;
}

p:after {
    content: '"';
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas commodo semper nulla at consectetur. Quisque at aliquam turpis, eu rhoncus dolor. Aliquam quis aliquam ante. Suspendisse tempus, erat eget scelerisque rhoncus, lacus eros luctus ante, a consequat quam tortor a quam. Suspendisse congue, ipsum sit amet venenatis ornare, ligula tortor fermentum est, et aliquet augue nisl id leo. Suspendisse gravida nisl in arcu condimentum gravida. Maecenas aliquam nisi nec congue viverra. Duis at lacinia justo.</p>
```

---

Edit:

It was pointed out that the negative margin is `-.4em` because that happens to be about the width of a quote character in the given font, since it is a variable-width font.

A non-font-specific solution could be to make the item 1em wide, then align the text to the right:

```
p:before {
  content: '"';
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1em;
  width: 1em;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! Could you add a background color so we can see the hanging indent?

Comment: @mheiber added a BG color for you. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Is it always .4em? Or does it depend on the font?

Comment: How do you detect punctuation in the middle of a paragraph?

Comment: @Costa the `-.4em` would depend on the font. Specifically it is how wide the punctuation character is in the chosen font, since each letter is a different width in non-fixed-width fonts. If it was a fixed-width front then it would just be `-1em`.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike, thanks, that's helpful! Of course, it makes building a library that solves the problem this way a little more difficult.

Comment: @Costa see my edit above. I added another version of the CSS that would allow the use of any font by aligning the text to the right and making it `1em` wide, instead of using the `-.4em` margin. This CSS would be more "universal" across different fonts.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike that's genius. It's amazing what one line of CSS can simplify.

Comment: This worked great for hanging punctuation on the right, but slightly changing the example above like so: 

    p:after {
        content: '.';
        position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
        margin-right: -.4em;
    }

Answer (score 3):

You can use a negative text-indent:

```css
blockquote p {
  text-indent: -.4em;
  background-color: #faebbc;
}
```

```html
<p>There's a block quote on the next line:</p>
<blockquote><p>"I have negative text indent."</p></blockquote>
```

(tip adapted from http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hanging-punctuation/)

Comment: This is only good for the first line in a body of text, right?